# Why is the first parameter of a $.get callback function not equal to the server response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, content-type

I make the following requests:

```
$.when(
        $.get("/locator1"),
        $.get("/locator2")
    ).done(function(locator1Location, locator2Location) {   
        const url1 = locator1Location.url;  
        console.log("url1 " + JSON.stringify(locator1Location);
        //... more code
    });
```

According to the dev console, the get response from the server `/locator1` is:

`{"url":"http://localhost:8009"}`

But `locator1Location` is:

```
url1 [{"url":"http://localhost:8009"},"success",{"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"url\":\"http://localhost:8009\"}","responseJSON":{"url":"http://localhost:8009"},"status":200,"statusText":"success"}]
```

Why is `locator1Location` set to this instead of `{"url":"http://localhost:8009"}`?

The response header has a Content-Type of `application/prs.hal-forms+json`.

**Update**

If I only specify one `$.get` I get the expected response in `locator1Location`:

```
$.when(
        $.get("/locator1")
    ).done(function(locator1Location) { 
        const url1 = locator1Location.url;  
        console.log("url1 " + JSON.stringify(locator1Location);
        //... more code
    });
```

Console outptut is:

`url1 {"url":"http://localhost:8009"}`

Why doesn't this get returned when making two $.get calls?

Comment: That might just be how .when works

Comment: @DanielA.White - Perhaps but other places I'm using .when is just returning response JSON data as provided by the server. I'm trying to understand why the behavior is different for these two calls. I thought the Content-Type might be the issue since it was different from my other calls but I just changed it to match the others and I still get that odd response.